# How to post feed via Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

I'm new to Facebook SDK, and I'm trying to publish text to Facebook.

According to [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api), I did this:

```
public void postmessage(View v)
{
  String m="test";

Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
 Log.i("log",session.getAccessToken());


  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://graph.facebook.com/100002172912180/feed?message="+m+"&access_token="+session.getAccessToken());

    try {

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        Log.i("log","send");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Log.i("log",response.toString()+"end");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } 

}
```

The token is right, because I can get right message from it. 
But the message can't publish. 
I didn't get any error message, instead, there is no message at all.
I can't figure out what's wrong with it, anyone can help?

Comment: Try to add a log in your catch block

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to GhostDerfel, this is easy to solve when the exception print out.
The http post needs to run in a thread. so here is the solution:

```
new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://graph.facebook.com/100002172912180/feed?message=test&access_token="+session.getAccessToken());

                HttpResponse response;
                try {
                    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                      Log.i("tag",EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              ;
            }
        }.start();
```

Hope this will help those who stuck with same problem.
:)